# Passing manipulated variables from one function to be used in another function

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

I am using a brute force tactic to finding the answer solution to my problem. The idea is I loop through 3 different ranges, e.g. a nested loop, in increments of 10 to significantly decrease the number of combinations.

I then take the three solutions given to me in my first function, to redefine the looping range parameter for my function that will yield a more precise solution.

This is my code:

```
# first broad looping function to zone down to the relevant area of my solution
def t1_solve(cgoal):
    max_value = None
    nc_f = None
    c_f = None
    cd_f = None
    for i, j, k in [(i,j,k) for i in range(nc_rev.idxmax(),int((cgoal*100)+200),5) for 
    j in range(c_rev.idxmax(),int((cgoal*100)+200),5) for k in range(cd_rev.idxmax(),
    int((cgoal*100)+200),5)]:
        if (t1rev(i,j,k) > max_value and t1c(i,j,k) > cgoal):

            #storing the optimal value result, and my three solution in nc_f, c_f, cd_f

            max_value = t1rev(i,j,k)
            nc_f = i
            c_f = j
            cd_f = k

    print max_value
    print nc_f, c_f, cd_f
    return nc_f
    return c_f
    return cd_f

# second reduced looping problem to fine-tune my answer

def t1_finetune():

# run the broad looping function

    t1_solve(3.61)

# this is where I have trouble with passing my solutions stored in the
# previous function's nc_f, c_f, cd_f

#ERROR OCCURS HERE!!!!!
    if nc_f - 20 > 0:
        nc_lowerbound = nc_f - 20
    else:
        nc_lowerbound = 1

    if nc_f + 20 < 1499:
        nc_upperbound = nc_f + 20
    else:
        nc_upperbound = 1499

    if c_f - 20 > 0:
        c_lowerbound = c_f - 20
    else:
        c_lowerbound = 1

    if c_f + 20 < 1499:
        c_upperbound = c_f + 20
    else:
        c_upperbound = 1499

    if cd_f - 20 > 0:
        cd_lowerbound = cd_f - 20
    else:
        cd_lowerbound = 1

    if cd_f + 20 < 1499:
        cd_upperbound = cd_f + 20
    else:
        cd_upperbound = 1499    

    for i, j, k in [(i,j,k) for i in range(nc_lowerbound, nc_upperbound) for 
    j in range(c_lowerbound, c_upperbound) for k in range(cd_lowerbound, cd_upperbound)]:
        if (t1rev(i,j,k) > max_value and t1c(i,j,k) > cgoal):
            max_value = t1rev(i,j,k)
            nc_f = i
            c_f = j
            cd_f = k
    print max_value
    print nc_f, c_f, cd_f
    return nc_f, c_f, cd_f


t=time.time()
t1_finetune()
print time.time() - t
```

The error message I get is:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'nc_f' referenced before assignment
```

Essentially, I just need to pass nc_f, c_f, and cd_f from my t1_solve() to my t1_finetune(). Running t1_solve() on its own works fine, and when it gets called in t1_finetune(), it still works up until it goes on to the rest of the code where I commented the error occurence.

I hope this is clear, please let me know if there is anything I can clarify.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Apero: I first read this question on a cell phone and had no idea what the problem was, so I feel your pain. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your `t1_solve` function has three `return` statements instead of one. As soon as the first one is reached, the function is over, and the other ones never happen. So, you need this:

```
return nc_f, c_f, cd_f
```

---

Next, when you call `t1_solve` and it returns those values to you, you just ignore the results. You need to store them somewhere. For example:

```
nc_f, c_f, cd_f = t1_solve(3.61)
```

---

For an intuitive understanding, what you're doing here is returning three values instead of one, and assigning those three return values to three variables.

If you want to know what's *actually* happening: The first `nc_f, c_f, cd_f` creates a single 3-element tuple and returns that one tuple. Then, the later `nc_f, c_f, cd_f =` uses iterable assignment unpacking. See the tutorial section [Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) for a nice introduction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @abarnet, I'm new to Python and didn't quite understand how those returned values get used again. Storing them was the key here. Thanks again!